# Django save some fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

When I press "Upload" i have error: UNIQUE constraint failed: main_profile.user_id. Where do you need to insert the profile id?

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="pic">Загрузить фото:</label>
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, user_name):
user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ImageForm(
        request.POST,
        request.FILES,
        instance=Profile(user=user)
    )

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save() #When I put commit=False the error disappears, but image don`t save
        return redirect('/')
else:
    form = ImageForm()

return render(request, "profile.html", {"profile_data": user,
                                        'form': form})
```

models.py
User class extension

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Фото", upload_to="images/profile", default="images/profile/profile.png",
                          blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from main.models import Profile

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('photo', )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the relationship between `Profile` and `User` to be one-to-one, meaning that for every user, they can have no more than one profile. I would imagine that the user that you're trying to create a profile for already has one in the database, causing it to throw an error.